# Query optimisation for multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query:

```
SELECT columns
FROM tableA A
JOIN tableB B ON A.column1 = B.column1
JOIN tableC C ON A.column2 = C.column2
WHERE A.column3 = 1
```

I have a nonclustered index on columnC with Column2,1 as included columns. tableA has 60 million records, tableB has 4.4 million records and table C has 4 million records.

This query takes 20 minutes to execute. Is there a way to optimise this query?

Comment: Please provide your execution plan

Comment: There is no columnC in your query. Please include actual create table and create index clauses + statistics io output (+ the query plan you were asked already)

Comment: How many rows have `Column3 = 1` and how many rows does the query return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering A.column3=1 where clause first and then go for JOIN.
Also look if you can use 'ADD' condition to save more exe time.

Comment: I tried to filter the same first. Still the time is around 18minutes.